# C and for loops

Tags: c, for-loop, fread

I am seeking to a certain position in the file to get an entry count (which tells how many time to do the for loop). can i simply do it like this? i am kind of new to C so please take it easy on me 
Any input will be valuable. and please dont give me a working program, just tell me if the condition of the for loop would work and if it wouldnt, how i couldpossibly fix it.
We can use an example of the `entryCount = 40` from fread

psuedocode ofcourse:

```
unsigned char buffer[8]
fseek (file to position where entry count is);
entryCount = fread (buffer, sozeof(buffer), 1, in);
// cound i just fread(**entryCount**, sizeof(buffer), 1, in); ?

for ( x = 0; x < entryCount; x++ ) {
// execute code as many time is stored in "entryCount"
}

continue script ect
```

thanks for looking and for your valuable input

Comment: okay, this is pseudo code, I got it, but have you tried something *real* actually? have you tried to read the error messages? have you googled about opening/closing/reading/writing files in C?

Comment: yes, i can open one file and read and open another and write, i just wanted to get some ideas about the for-loop and if varables could be passed to the condition statement in the for-loop. i wrote a program in perl that uses this loop, but perl is more flexible than C.

Comment: If your question is about how to loop _entryCount_ times, your for-loop looks OK. Note that the value of x is `0..eC-1`, so it's useful for array indices. If you need `1..eC` instead, you could write `for ( x = 1; x <= entryCount; x++ )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

almost correct:

1. you need to have a int declaration for x (or whatever var)
2. more of a suggestion - 'i' is usually used for loop variables

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < entryCount; i++ ) {
     // execute code as many time is stored in "entryCount"
   }
   ```

Comment: awesome, thats exactly what i needed to know, one other question about fread, could i just do something like fread(entryCount, sozeof(buffer), 1, in); or would i need to do something like entryCount = fread(buffer, sozeof(buffer), 1, in); then go into the forloop with entryCount

Comment: "i" being used is a hoary old tradition dating back to the days of FORTRAN, where I through N first letters of variable names declared them to be integers. Please try to use more descriptive names for variables (such as `row` and `col`). Making code more understandable for programmers/maintainers is much more important than being short.

Comment: int entryCount = fread(buffer, sozeof(buffer), 1, in); would be the correct way to do it

Comment: @Phil Perry yes but in generic loops i is used whether it stands for iterator/index or an old FORTRAN programming tradition is irrelevant. x, y, row, col are used in a co-ordinate or positional based loop, and this is not based on position or co-ordinates. In math the only reason we use x is also tradition so i don't see your point. In this case I would be using 'i' because this is just a temporary variable and the more descriptive ones should be used for more important variables.